# Facebook Authorization for Django Admin

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-admin

I want to use Facebook Authorization for Django Admin. Only the app developer (me) should be able to login. Is it possible? easily? and How?

Actually, I am even thinking to provide some special graph actions inside it. So, I should be able to play with the admin easily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [django social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) as an authentication means. Basically, it allows you to authenticate users as django `User`'s. You are then in "Standard Djangoland", where users that have the `is_staff` flag can access the admin, and those that don't can't.

You can therefore give the Facebook user that Social Auth created for you the appropriate privileges (that is `is_staff = True`) so that you can access the admin

There's a bit of a chicken & egg problem here, but you could use the `manage.py` console to make your user an admin user / superuser.